# Usage of not in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/)

```
$("#Maindiv:not('.Buttonclass')").live("click",function(){
divclick();
});

function divclick(){
alert("div");
};
$(".Buttonclass").live("click",function(){
buttonclick();
});
function buttonclick(){
alert("button");
};
```

When i click on the button both "div" click and button click are getting called, i want only button to be called and not the div click function. What am i missing in the not selector?

Comment: Be aware, as for jQuery 1.9, live is dead...

Answer (score 3):

Try with the `event.stopPropagation()` mehtod.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/2/)

```
$(".Buttonclass").live("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
buttonclick();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `event.stopPropagation`: [DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/7/)

```
$(".Buttonclass").live("click",function(e){
buttonclick();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This is similar answer as others already posted and btw here `e` is undefined. Here, you are stopping propagation because of an unhandled js error

Comment: @A.Wolff  Sorry for the error, but that was a honest attempt from me. Will edit the  code snippet

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()` for child button to prevent event getting propogated from parent click event.

```
function buttonclick(event){
 alert("button");
 event.stopPropagation()
};
```

**[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

First prefer [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as it is already deprecated and removed in jquery 1.9

```
$(document).on("click", "#Maindiv", function (e) {
    divclick();
});
$(document).on("click", '#Maindiv .Buttonclass', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8sh5y/)

Comment: ya, OP should use on()

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `:not` selector here. You're problem is event bubbling related. A click event will bubble up to the document root, so when you click on a button inside a div, the button will get clicked first, then the event will bubble up to its parent element (the div in this case) and so on.

You can explicitly prevent this behavious by calling `event.stopPropagation();`.This will stop the event from bubbling up further at the moment as it is called.

See the fixed http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/5/

```
$(".Buttonclass").live("click",function(e){
    buttonclick();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/3269863) for further information about bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Maindiv").live("click",function(){
    divclick();
});

function divclick(){
    alert("div");
};
$(".Buttonclass").live("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    buttonclick();
});
function buttonclick(){
    alert("button");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afFLB/6/

This is what you want.
Stop Propagation.